# If I stayed in a hotel for 6 months, should I list that as an address where I lived?

Tags: visas, uk, applications

I'm filling in a UK visa application and it asks:

> Have you lived at any other addresses in the UK or abroad on the past 2 years?

I have put my current address and the address I lived in over the past 2 years. During that 2-year period I travelled to Dubai and ended up staying there for about 6 months. I was on holiday but had to prolong my stay. Basically stayed in a hotel the whole time. Do I have to include this as one of the addresses?

Comment: Can’t find an official source for this but IMHO if you maintained a permanent address elsewhere during the entire two years, you don’t need to include your hotel stay. If you didn’t, then I would include it.  If you were just in Dubai as a tourist IIRC the application will ask for details of countries you’ve visited in the past 10 years.

Comment: @Traveller that sounds like an answer (though given the point in last sentence I suppose it would not make much of a difference either way; in any case the application will give a clear picture of the applicant's movements).

Comment: Thanks you both. I appreciate the speedy reply

Answer (score 2):

Turning my comment into an answer:

Can’t find an official source for this but IMHO if you maintained a permanent address elsewhere during the entire two years you don’t need to include your hotel stay. If you didn’t, then I would include it. If you were just in Dubai as a tourist IIRC the application asks for details of countries you’ve visited in the past 10 years.